# how to show that $ \frac{\theta e^t(1-\theta)}{(1-\theta+\theta e^t)^2} \leq\frac{1}{4}$?

Tags: probability, inequality, integral-inequality, moment-generating-functions, upper-lower-bounds

let  $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ , then how to show that $\forall t\in R$
 $$ \frac{\theta e^t(1-\theta)}{(1-\theta+\theta e^t)^2} \leq\frac{1}{4}?$$

This is a step of a proof of [hoffeding's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma).

Comment: Probabilistic proof?

$$ \frac{p e^{t}(1-p)}{(1-p+p e^t)^2}$$ looks like mgfs of binomial, bernoulli or something or some combination

Comment: @BCLC actually this  is a step of prove of hoffeding's lemma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe start with $4\theta e^t(1-\theta)\leq(1-\theta+\theta e^t)^2$ from the inequality $$4xy\leq(x+y)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

With 
$$\left|\alpha+\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\right|\geq2$$
then let $$\alpha=\sqrt{\dfrac{\theta}{1-\theta}}e^{\frac12t}$$
gives the desire inequality after simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Just using algebra
$$f(t)=\frac{\theta e^t(1-\theta)}{(1-\theta+\theta e^t)^2}$$
$$f'(t)=\frac{(\theta -1) \theta  e^t \left(\theta +\theta  e^t-1\right)}{\left(\theta 
   \left(e^t-1\right)+1\right)^3}$$
So, the first derivative cancels for
$$\theta +\theta  e^{_*}t-1=0 \implies t_*=\log \left(\frac{1-\theta }{\theta }\right)\implies f(t_*)=\frac 14$$

Computing the second derivative, $f''(t_*)=-\frac 18$ confirms that $t_*$ corresponds to a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Observe $p(1-p) \le \frac 1 4$ (That's probably where the $\frac 1 4$ comes from). We will be finished if we can prove

$$ \frac{e^t}{(1-p+p e^t)^2} \le 1$$

Just modify proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2905848) then.

Answer (score 0):

Pf: Observe that the numerator can be written as a product of 2 terms whose sum is inside the $()^2$ of the denominator, so by [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we have that for $x=1-p>0$ and $y=pe^t > 0$

$$\frac{xy}{(x+y)^2} \le \frac 1 4$$

QED